# Creating extendable datasets in parallel HDF5

Tags: c++, boost, parallel-processing, mpi, hdf5

I am trying to write data into an hdf5 file in parallel.  Each node has its own dataset, which is unique (although they are the same size).  I am trying to write them all into separate datasets in an hdf5 file in parallel.  The catch is that later I may want to overwrite them with different size datasets (different size compared to the original set of datasets --- the dataset on each processor is the same size).  Does anyone know how to do this?

(code relies on boost and Eigen)

I have code to first open the file:

```
boost::mpi::environment env(argc, argv);

// set up the info for HDF5 and MPI
MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_SELF;
MPI_Info info = MPI_INFO_NULL;

// Set up file access property list with parallel I/O access
hid_t plist_id = H5Pcreate(H5P_FILE_ACCESS);
H5Pset_fapl_mpio(plist_id, comm, info);

// declare the file ID
std::string filename = "test.h5";

// create a file
hid_t fileID = H5Fcreate(filename.c_str(), H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, plist_id);

// close the property list
H5Pclose(plist_id);
```

Then to create and write the datasets:

```
// get the mpi communicator
unique_ptr<mpi::communicator> worldComm(new mpi::communicator);

const Eigen::VectorXd dataset = worldComm->rank() * Eigen::VectorXd::Ones(3);
const std::string name = "/vector";

// sleep for a bit so the processors are doing something different
sleep(worldComm->rank() * 2.0);

// the sizes of the data set
const hsize_t dimsf[2] = {(hsize_t)dataset.rows(), (hsize_t)dataset.cols()};

// set the maximum size of the data set to be unlimited
const hsize_t maxdim[2] = {H5S_UNLIMITED, H5S_UNLIMITED};

// the size of each chuck --- is there a better way to choose these numbers!?!?!?!
const hsize_t chunkDims[2] = {2, 5};

// create the dataspace for the dataset.
const hid_t filespace = H5Screate_simple(2, dimsf, maxdim); 
assert(filespace>0);

// modify data set creation properties --- enable chunking
const hid_t prop = H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_CREATE);
const hid_t status = H5Pset_chunk(prop, 2, chunkDims);

// create the dataset with default properties for each process
std::vector<hid_t> dsetVec(worldComm->size());
for( int i=0; i<worldComm->size(); ++i ) {
  const std::string datasetName = name+"_rank_"+std::to_string(i);

  dsetVec[i] = H5Dcreate2(fileID, datasetName.c_str(), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, filespace, H5P_DEFAULT, prop, H5P_DEFAULT);
}

// Create property list for dataset write.
const hid_t plistID = H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_XFER);

// write the data to file
H5Dwrite(dsetVec[worldComm->rank()], H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, plistID, dataset.data());

// close the filespace 
H5Sclose(filespace);

// close the datasets
for( int i=0; i<worldComm->size(); ++i ) {
  H5Dclose(dsetVec[i]);
}

// close the file
H5Fclose(fileID);
```

What I expect is four datasets named "/vector_rank_i" (i=0,1,2,3) each of size 3 and valued [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], and [3, 3, 3], respectively.  However, what is being produced is four datasets named "/vector_rank_i" (i=0,1,2,3) each of size 3 but the values are [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], and [3, 3, 3].

This exact code works perfectly if I don't use chunking.  However, since I'll need to be able to extend the datasets later this is less than ideal.  Does anyone know a good work around?

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your specific code, I'd like to know more about why "one dataset per process" is how you chose to decompose your problem.  That seems like a mess if you're ever going to scale beyond a handful of processes.

You are doing parallel I/O to a dataset, and you have enabled MPI-IO but not  collective access.  that's unlikely to yield terribly good performance at scale.

Your chunk dims seem really small to me.  I'd make them larger, but "how large" depends on a lot of factors.  Well, see how performance is with these values. Maybe it won't be so bad if you turn on collective I/O?

Those initial impressions aside, perhaps you simply wish to experiment with HDF5.  I don't know why turning chunking on would make some datasets empty... unless you are writing to NFS.   If you are writing to NFS, well, good luck, buddy but it's hopeless.